# Cannot change credentials for wso2 api manager Analytics

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-streaming-integrator

I have a API Manager 2.6.0 deployment within 3 nodes i.e. 3 VMs. Abbreviations:

1. GW - Gateway
2. AIO - Traffic Manager, Key Manager, Dev portal, Publisher
3. Analytucs - Api M Analytics 2.6.0
4. DB - PostgreSQL.

I've set everything working between components, till I changed the default admin password, username stood the same.
As per manual I did

1. Changed the admin password from UI, sice I did a tests already with default credentials
2. Changed password in api-manager.xml on AIO and GW
3. Changed password in user-mgt.xml on AIO and GW
4. Changed password in jndi.properties on AIO and GW

Above 4 points as noted in manual- https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Maintaining+Logins+and+Passwords 
This manual does not tell how to make distributed analytics node to accept that password.

The Analytics Install [manual](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+APIM+Analytics#StandardSetup) told to install WSO2 API-M Analytics and WSO2 API-M(which as I understand is meant if both are on same machine). Again, this manual does not tell much about user configuring on Analytics server.

I tried to look from DAS and SP [manual](https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP430/User+Management+via+the+IdP+Client+Interface), but the Analytics does not have auth.configs: in YAML files and nor adding them manually from SP source code helps.

Error returned on GW and AIO:

> 2019-02-21 15:13:52,090 [-] [DataBridge-ConnectionService-tcp://192.168.102.39:7612-pool-11-thread-1] ERROR DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://192.168.102.39:7712.
>   org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://192.168.102.39:7712.
>
> Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: Error while trying to login to the data receiver.
>
> Caused by: ThriftAuthenticationException(message:wrong userName or password)

On Analytics obvious:

> [2019-02-21 15:16:49,016] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.authentication.CarbonAuthenticationHandler} - Authentication failed for username 'admin'. Error : 'Invalid_Credentials'. Error Description : 'The login credential used for login are invalid, username : 'admin'.'
>   [2019-02-21 15:16:49,016] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.authentication.Authenticator} - wrong userName or password

The question is, how to make WSO2 APIM Analytics(2.6.0) node, which is separated from API Manager, to accept the changed credentials.

Last tought is do I need to connect Analytics to Carbon DB?

Comment: What do you mean by "nor adding them manually from SP source code helps"? Was the configs you added any different from the one in the answer?

Comment: No, exactly the same, i took that excerpt from Stream Processor config, now I've commented it out.
Aaaand that may be it. (facepalm), I'll try the encryption a bit later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add the auth.configs element to the conf/worker/deployment.yaml file, (Please note the password has to be The Base64(UTF-8) encrypted)

```
auth.configs: 
  type: 'local'
  userManager:
    adminRole: admin
    userStore:
      users:
       -
         user:
           username: admin
           password: YWRtaW4=
           roles: 1
      roles:
       -    
         role:
           id: 1
           displayName: admin
```

Comment: All the issue was within Base64 encryption, I somehow missed that..Thank you!

Comment: the = sign at the end of the string is a sign! sign of base 64 most of the times! :-)